# What is the advantage of a product variant?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am confused by product variants in Hybris.

For example, why would you choose to use a variant for size or color?

Wouldn't expanding the product item to include both style and size as attributes simplify the resulting data model?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure why you edited the title.  This is a hybris specific concept and I would want this to be reflected in the title.

Answer (score 4):

Variants are a common concept in eCommerce systems. Hybris supports this as do others:

- http://docs.shopify.com/api/product_variant
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms962267%28v=cs.70%29.aspx
- http://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/products.html

So why do we do this? Mainly this is for ease of management.

If we take an Apparel example, perhaps we have Products with no size or colour (maybe sunglasses) variations, we have products with only Colour variations (hats?) and we have Products with Size and Colour variations (t-shirts perhaps).

Here is our setup:

- Product

  - Product Blue

    - Product Blue/S
  - Product Red

    - Product Red/M
  - Product Green

    - Product Green/S
    - Product Green/XL

In this example we need configure only one Price, on 'Product'. We need only configure 3 images, on 'Product Blue', 'Product Red' and 'Product Green'. We can then configure Stock Levels on the "leaf" variants.

So different products will have different numbers of variations and different ways to vary. As a result we don't want to fill up the Product table with lots of Null columns representing all these possible variations for every product. A more extensible approach is taken via the VariantType MetaType.

Via this approach you can create 'concrete' Variants (as I call them) via your items.xml, or 'dynamic' Variants via run time definition using impex. Only concrete Variants can be used in code directly (i.e. using instanceof) but cannot be added with a deployment and an updatesystem. Dynamic variants require more clever coding to determine the VariantAttributes on the item but this is in general a much better approach and more extensible.

There is of course an argument that multi level variant structures are a bit redundant and slightly false. There is no "direction" to variants. You do not naturally navigate Product > Blue > Small, you simply select the Blue Small Product. So it could be argued that all variant structures should only be 1 level deep.

Comment: Thanks your input.  I am not sure I fully understood it since typically in hybris the product variant is persisted on the same table as product. So there will be many product level records which will ultimately have null values because as you stated this is really only one level deep and there is no direction.  Also, I am not certain what you mean by Price being set at the product level. Could it not be that a certain variant has different pricing and that you would have to set sku specific prices?

Comment: The price was an example of how it can be used to reduce management overhead. It could be applied to any attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a variant product to manage the price for example. For some colors it could be possible that the product will cost more than for another color. You can't manage this in one product. Also it is possible that you will define another description / productname for your variant product. It is way easier to do this with a variant product than using the custom product.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But product variants and base products are stored in the same table. So why would managing price be easier?  I also don't see how defining the product name or description becomes easier using variant product.  Could you please elaborate and/or possibly provide an example?